# LIBSSH2_ERROR_SFTP_PROTOCOL

Tags: libssh2

When using SFTP connection to read the flat file from MFT server, it is only reading 64kb of data and after 64kb it is returning -31. We are using LIBSSH2 1.9.0 version

we tried to read the data from flat file of size (>1 mb) from the MFT server, it is returning -31 after reading 64kb of data. Issue is only when the source file is in MFT server.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.